# EC2 instances keep becoming inaccessible via SSH, what could issue be? Can I use elastic loadbalancer to check SSH connectivity?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, private-key

This is mainly an issue for my development ec2 server as it seems that my instance keeps becoming inaccessible via SSH. It happened yesterday so I killed that one and started a new one and happened again later today. The server still works, my web application is accessible in a web browser but whenever I try to connect via SSH I get a `permission denied (private key)` error message in my terminal. I am 100% sure I am doing nothing wrong as I can create a new instance of the exact same AMI (its a personal custom AMI), change absolutely nothing, including using the same `.pem key`, and then am able to SSH into that new instance using the exact same command as before (just changing the IP address).

I understand that ec2 can have issues but having this happen every day seems a bit odd.. I am using an `m2.xlarge` instance so I don't know if these tend to be unstable, in the past I have used a small instance and had it running for months with no problems which is why I find this so odd.

I am looking into using loadbalancing but it seems the only "health" checks they offer is for http or tcp so I'm not sure if I can make it monitor for SSH connectivity. This is important for development as I may make 1-2 new pushes of an application a day and use SSH to do this. I have a designer that needs to have the app always accessible as he works with the front-end files to test output with the live application. Anyways, any advice / info is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I tend to attach and keep the same public elastic ip on instances, so the lack of a stable ip, depending on your client setup, might be connected with the problem to a certain degree.

Depending on the distribution you are using, you could look into /var/log/auth.log or /var/log/syslog to have some more debug info about what's going on ...

Are you using a Unix terminal or some other kind of terminal application to login?